# JS doesn't pick values from html

Tags: javascript

Here is my code. I want to make function which takes values from inputs, multiply them and put result to paragraph.

```
function price() {

var x = document.getElementById("widthOfGlass").value;

var y = document.getElementById("heightOfGlass").value;

var price1 = 150;

    return x * y * 0.0001 * price1;
};

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Price is " + price();
```

And here is HTML:

```
< input type="text" id="widthOfGlass">

< input type="text" id="heightOfGlass">

< input type="button" onclick='price()' value="Show price" />

< p id="demo">< /p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t1ymn6gq/)

The problem with your code was that, you were not setting the `innerHTML` of `#demo` after the calculation is done.You are just setting it once, on page load.

Thus, to get the desired output, change your Javascript as follows.

```
function price() {
    var x = document.getElementById("widthOfGlass").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("heightOfGlass").value;
    var price1 = 150;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Price is " + x * y * 0.0001 * price1;
};
```

and remember that there is no need to return the calculated value.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Price is " +
```

As it is, above line of script only runs at load time.

You want to run that when the button is clicked, something like this:

```
function price() {

var x = document.getElementById("widthOfGlass").value;

var y = document.getElementById("heightOfGlass").value;

var price1 = 150;

    var res =  x * y * 0.0001 * price1;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Price is " + res;
};
```